# How to input text other than english, like bangla or arabic in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a an application I need to input multilingual text through form to store in my DB. At this point I am getting '?????' question signs if I input any other than English language.

Comment: You only need to use a font for specific language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is problem of your database encoding. If you use the mysql, database's charset must be utf8mb4.

Comment: The perfect answer. The problem was in my DB charset collation.